# CriteriaBuilder order by result of operations

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose the following entity:

```
Entity {
    Integer id;
    Boolean imported;
    Integer status;
}
```

The task is: When selecting entities those with `imported = true` AND `status != 1` should go to the bottom of search result. It is also necessary to use `CriteriaBuilder`.

I decided to compute the value which will indicate them to be pulled down by the following expression: `imported = true AND status != 1`

If writing direct SQL it works as intended having a look:

```
SELECT .. FROM .. ORDER BY (imported = true AND status != 1) ASC
```

However I cannot transcode it in context of `CriteriaBuilder`

I tried to do it like this:

```
Predicate eqTruePredicate = cb.equal(root.get(Entity_.imported), true);
Predicate neqStatusPredicate = cb.notEqual(root.get(Entity_.status)), 1);

Predicate andExp = cb.and(eqTruePredicate, neqStatusPredicate);
order.add(0, new OrderImpl(cb.isTrue(andExp)));
```

The generated query is the following:

```
order by ( generatedAlias0.imported=:param2 ) and ( generatedAlias0.status<>:param3 ) asc
```

But when execute the exception is thrown saying: "unexpected AST node" pointing at token `and`

Is there a way to perform ordering by computed value using `CriteriaBuilder` and what would be necessary to be done?

**Addition:** Hibernate ORM version: 4.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using `CASE` statement:

```
Expression<Integer> caseExp = cb.<Integer>selectCase()
    .when(
        cb.and(
            cb.equal(root.get(Entity_.imported), true),
            cb.notEqual(root.get(Entity_.status), 1)
        ),
        1
    )
    .otherwise(0);

order.add(0, cb.asc(caseExp));
```

This results into an `ORDER BY` statement like this:

```
order by case when ( entity.imported=true ) and ( entity.status<>1 ) then 1 else 0 end asc
```